# Problem with removing subdocument mongodb c#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to remove subdocument called "Data", but my code didn't work

```
var update = Update.Pull("Meta.$.Data", new BsonDocument(){
                { } // I dont know what I should write in BsonDocument
            });
```

Here's an example of document

```
        "_id" : 2,
        "RefId" : null,
        "RefIdStr" : "32",
        "Meta" : {
            "DatabaseRouting" : "{replicaSetName:company}",
            "Data" : "{id:1,name:Centrum ,phoneNumber:,nip:76"

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem $unset help me:

```
Database.GetCollection(Users).Update(query, Update.Unset("Meta.Data"));
```